# MSpec and ReSharper test runner shows specification as PASSED when all its tests FAILED

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, mspec

Is this a bug, or expected behaviour? When using MSpec and ReSharper, in the top pane my specification has clearly failed, but the bottom pane shows it as Passed.

[image: R# shows both PASS and FAIL for a specification]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with ReSharper. I tried failing the context explicitly but it still shows up as green. I'll contact JetBrains about it.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Just to close the loop, here's the reply I got from Alexander Berezoutsky of JetBrains: 
"I apologize – I’ve missed the part of your original email about using MSpec. Since it’s not ReSharper’s out of the box feature, we’re not fully supporting this. However, we’re trying to keep in touch with plugin developers, so I’ve forwarded your bug-report to the corresponding person about this MSpec issue."